# Set height and width of div containing dynamically added image

Tags: c#, html

how can i set the height and width of a div as that of the image contained in it ? the image is provided dynamically and the height and width of div keep changing with the image.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the div is set to be `runat="server"` and give the div an id property.

Then in your C# code

```
divID.Attributes.Add("height", heightValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"></div>
```

codeBehined:

```
div1.Style["width"] = image.Width + "";
div1.Style["height"] = image.Height + "";
```